# How to move to new release in Github?

Tags: git, github

I have a master branch which is the deployment branch for production.
There's a `0.2` release and `0.2` tag associated with this branch.

Now, we want to move to next release i.e. release `0.3`. What are the steps I need to take? What is the general flow? That we keep the source code as it is for 0.2 release isn't?
If I create a new release and tag `0.3` and point it to master branch the old release will also be updated with every merge, isn't? As both are attached to master branch.

I don't think there a way to retag branch for a release in GitHub. I'll have to re-create them which is not the intention.

How should I proceed with new release and tag creation and attaching it to master, yet, keeping the old release 0.2 source code preserved.

Comment: Maybe you should think about using [Git Flow](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.html). Nevertheless, you can simply create a new branch from an old commit or tag and continue to work on them.

Comment: Both branches and tags are just synonyms for specific commits. The old tag won't update when the branch changes.

Comment: This is not a programming question and there is no "right" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tags point at specific commits, not to a branch as such, so will remain pointing to where it originally did even if you add more stuff. However branches do move if you push new material to them. Thus if you tag master (say as 0.2), add new stuff to the branch, and then tag again (0.3?), the 0.2 will still be as before but 0.3 will be the up-to-date version.

If you need to update 0.2 then you can add a new branch (updated-0.2??) and add there. Typically releases would then be 0.2.1 etc. Some people (myself including) often work by creating a release branch off master and then create the release tag - there are pros and cons either way. If you never do "hotfix" versions, and always fix forward, then you won't have this issue and can ignore.